# How to create a type with n possible values in Lisp

Tags: class, haskell, types, lisp, ternary

I've been learning Common Lisp this week, toying a bit with it. As an exercise, I would like to translate some Haskell code I had written to simulate balanced ternary. The core of it is the type:

Data Trit = Pos | Neutr | Neg

How do I declare a type of that kind in Lisp? The idea is that this type should only have three possible values.

Comment: You can do `(deftype ternary () '(member :pos :neutr :neg))`, then `(check-type x ternary)` when you want to check the type of `x`.

Comment: Yes, perfect, thanks! I'll close the question now.

Answer (score 0):

In Common Lisp programs, you will simply use symbols `'Pos`, `'Neutr` and `'Neg`.

If you really need a specific type, you could refer to:
[Common Lisp equivalent to C enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578290/common-lisp-equivalent-to-c-enums) but I would suggest to keep it simple and stay with `'Pos`, `'Neutr` and `'Neg`.